# How to read UTF-8 encoding with fscanf

Tags: utf-8, scanf, octave, iso-8859-1

Octave 4.2.2 reads `ISO-8859-1` chars with the `fscanf` command (formatted to read white spaces):

```
foo = fscanf(foofile1, "%*s %[^\n]");
```

while `fgetl` reads native `UTF-8`:

```
foo = fgetl(foofile2);
```

Both files showed to be encoded with `UTF-8`:

```
$ file -i foofile1.csv 
foofile1.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8

$ file -i foofile2.html
foofile2.html: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Is there any way to read the `HTML` file in `UTF-8` format with `fscanf`?

Update: As pointed out by @TS, this has been reported as a bug in [savannah.gnu.org](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?52681).

Comment: Does this workaround mentioned [here](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?52681#comment9) work: `deal(textscan(foofile1, "%*s %[^\n]"){:});` ?

Comment: Same result, @TS, it does not read in UTF-8 format.

Comment: Could you provide minimal examples (both ANSI and utf8) with the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

No change in code is needed. UTF8 is designed to work with most of non-UTF8-aware single-byte string functions like the above as far as you don't have to work with decoded codepoints, for example, to print the string to screen.

Comment: But both files are read differently. Special characters (like Á) are read with a single hex code (ISO-8859-1) or two hex codes (UTF-8), depending on the command used.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was the standard C function fscanf.